# Spring can't find configuration in path

Tags: java, spring, configuration, dependency-injection

well I'm runnning this code and it cant' find the springconfig4.xml file:

```
package com.nortal.pirs.test.independant;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Test4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/com/nortal/pirs/beans/springconfig4.xml");
        BeanFactory factory = context;
        Test3 instance = (Test3) factory.getBean("Test3");

        instance.run();
    }
}
```

I mean I was kind of expecting it not to work, because in Java it never works when you try to use a path that is not in your current package. However as many Spring tutorials I've seen, they all show this way of specifying the configuration file.

Now my springconfig4.xml is in my applications' src/com/nortal/pirs/beans folder. So how do I specify it so that it can be found here?

The current Test4 class is located in src/com/nortal/pirs/test/independant folder.

**My stacktrace:**

```
    2012-12-09 06:16:15,734 [main] INFO  org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@b24044e: startup date [Sun Dec 09 06:16:15 EET 2012]; root of context hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/asm/ClassVisitor
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.<init>(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.<init>(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:168)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.<init>(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:167)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.createBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:195)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:128)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:527)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:441)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.nortal.pirs.test.independant.Test4.main(Test4.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 10 more
```

**My springconfig4.xml:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.nortal.pirs.businesslogic.logic"></context:component-scan>
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.nortal.pirs.test.independant"></context:component-scan>

</beans>
```

Or is the problem somewhere else maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stacktrace points this:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor
```

You need to download the [spring-asm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-asm/3.1.2.RELEASE/spring-asm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar) file from the [maven repo](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-asm/3.1.2.RELEASE) (supposing that you are using spring 3.1.2) or if you are using maven, edit your `pom.xml` file and add the next lines:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, this line:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/com/nortal/pirs/beans/springconfig4.xml");
```

Has an error, the path must not start with a trailing `/`., so the path to the file becomes: `"com/nortal/pirs/beans/springconfig4.xml"`.

The [ClassPathResource javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.1.x/api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html#ClassPathResource%28java.lang.String%29) states that it will be removed anyways:

> Create a new ClassPathResource for ClassLoader usage. A leading slash
>   will be removed, as the ClassLoader resource access methods will not
>   accept it.

Comment: Thanks, yes, indeed the problem wasn't that it couldn't find the configuration file in the path, but it lacked some libraries like the org.springframework.asm

Comment: I was also required to add the respective jar to the WEB-INF/lib folder, then it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Exception says it is not finding a class, not Spring context xml

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor`

please add asm dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.springframework.asm</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: How exactly can I do that? I tried above the <context:... but the compiler said it wasn't allowed and the <dependancy> tag wasn't between suggestions either.

Comment: if you are using maven add that dependency snippet in pom.xml, other wise you will have to download the jar and put in WEB-INF/lib

Answer (score 2):

Add `spring-asm-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar` and `spring-expression-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar`.

Answer (score 1):

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor

Just add the spring-asm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar file. Place it in your lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

For the above problem as mentioned above these jars are missing namely 1.org.springframework.asm-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
2.org.springframework.expression-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
or 
Add all the **core Jars of Spring** so that any new programmer can Run all basic level programs.

There is no need of below line in your program. insted of that you can use **context** insted of **factory** in the above program.

**BeanFactory factory = context**

We usually use **ApplicationContext** insted of **BeanFactory**.
Even if you use BeanFactory there will be no effect for the program.

Answer (score 0):

Add the Jars which is shown in the Screen short and it will work[image]